# Collection view initialisation Query

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to initialize   collection view its showing incompatible type. I have written below code

```
UICollectionView * collCobj = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 260, 320, 230) collectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft];
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
uicollectionview collCobj
```

to

```
UICollectionView *collCobj
```

You probably miss `*` and missseplled the collection view class name.

**Edit**

Give proper parameter as layout. You are passing `UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft` as layout object which is wrong. Check this

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
UICollectionView *collCobj = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 260, 320, 230) collectionViewLayout:layout];
```

Comment: ya i have done it but problem is with collection view layout its showing incompatible

Comment: @haigowtham Did your issue resolved? what problem you are facing now?. This will not do anything with xcode

Comment: i have done   UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

    collectionViewObj=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0 , 320, 250) collectionViewLayout:layout];

    [collectionViewObj setDataSource:self];
    [collectionViewObj setDelegate:self];

    [collectionViewObj registerClass:[UICOllectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];


    [self.view addSubview:collectionViewObj]; but my app is crashing

Comment: [UICOllectionViewCell class] is again miss splelled [UICollectionViewCell class] is right. Use auto completion. If this is not the cause of crash put the crash log

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Initialize collection in proper manner
> ```

```
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

    collectionViewObj=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0 , 320, 250) collectionViewLayout:layout];

    [collectionViewObj setDataSource:self];
    [collectionViewObj setDelegate:self];

    [collectionViewObj registerClass:[Cell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];


    [self.view addSubview:collectionViewObj];
```

Comment: you have declared [Cell class] which object is cell

Comment: Cell is UICollectionViewCell Class.You can also create UICollectionVewCell class and name it as per your need.